# Can't create Rails app mounted NTFS partition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux

When I am trying to create a rails app in /dos partition in linux mint 18.1, it is throwing the following error

```
/home/akash/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/fileutils.rb:1345:in `chmod': Operation not permitted @ chmod_internal - /dos/projects/rails/little_farmers_family_daycare/bin (Errno::EPERM)
        from /home/akash/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/fileutils.rb:1345:in `chmod'
        from /home/akash/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/fileutils.rb:1026:in `block (2 levels) in chmod_R'
        from /home/akash/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/fileutils.rb:1478:in `preorder_traverse'
        from /home/akash/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/fileutils.rb:1024:in `block in chmod_R'
        from /home/akash/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/fileutils.rb:1023:in `each'
        from /home/akash/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/fileutils.rb:1023:in `chmod_R'
        from /home/akash/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor/actions/file_manipulation.rb:137:in `chmod'
        from /home/akash/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/app_generator.rb:17:in `chmod'
        from /home/akash/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/app_generator.rb:70:in `bin'
        from /home/akash/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/generators/app_base.rb:147:in `build'
        from /home/akash/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/app_generator.rb:217:in `create_bin_files'
        from /home/akash/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        from /home/akash/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
        from /home/akash/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `block in invoke_all'
        from /home/akash/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `each'
        from /home/akash/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `map'
        from /home/akash/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `invoke_all'
        from /home/akash/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor/group.rb:232:in `dispatch'
        from /home/akash/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor/base.rb:444:in `start'
        from /home/akash/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/application.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/akash/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
        from /home/akash/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
        from /home/akash/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/cli.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/akash/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
        from /home/akash/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
        from /home/akash/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/exe/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/akash/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/rails:22:in `load'
        from /home/akash/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/rails:22:in `<main>'
        from /home/akash/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
        from /home/akash/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

When I opened

> /home/akash/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/fileutils.rb:1345

the code in the 1345th line is

```
def chmod(mode)
  if symlink?
    File.lchmod mode, path() if have_lchmod?
  else
    File.chmod mode, path() #1345th line
  end
end
```

I couldn't understand the above code. Please help me

Note: Creating rails app in ext4 partition is working fine. I am using
ruby -2.4.0, rails -5.0.1

Comment: I'm not even sure this is a supported filesystem, it's missing critical things that are expected on POSIX. You may need to create it on your Linux filesystem, then copy it over once everything's in place. Even then there's no guarantee it will work going forward, a lack of permissions support is a big deal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
chmod(mode_int, file_name, ... )
```

Changes permission bits on the named file to the bit pattern represented by mode_int. Actual effects are operating system dependent. On Unix systems, see chmod for details. Returns the number of files processed.

You statically give permission

```
 File.chmod(0604, '/path/to/file')
```

rbenv install 2.3.0

Or you can find all files and directories that you might not have write access to by

```
find `rbenv root`/versions ! -perm -u+w
```

[chmod](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.1.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r1.bpxa500/chmod.htm)

Comment: I am using RVM for ruby and I didn't understand firstline. What is file_name?